# How to use wget behind a TMG proxy?

Tags: proxy, wget

I need to issue a HTTP request from the command line, but am behind a Forefront TMG Proxy. The environment variable `http_proxy` doesn't work.

I still get the error:

```
ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ).
```

I have no GUI (no X) on this PC.

How can I make a simple http request and bypass this proxy?

Answer (score 1):

For having authentication with `wget` you can use:

```
wget --proxy-user=user --proxy-password=pass http//someurl.com/file
```

If you want to set this as variable in the profile use:

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy.domain:8080"
```

Those are all you need. Of course, you should have a username:password for this proxy.

You could add the last line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or any script that executes at starting a prompt. If you want only `wget` knowing of this, you should modify `~/.wgetrc` (only for the user) or `/etc/wgetrc` (globally for all the users) and add:

```
proxy_password = pass
proxy_user = user
```